# Microsoft SQL Server : how to select single row/record when there are multiple dates of enrollment

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I believe and hope my question is pretty straight forward and easy to explain.

Basically I will have a record something along these lines:

John Doe has multiple periods of coverage:

```
    01-01-2014 --> 12-31-2014 ; 
    01-01-2015 --> 12-31-2015 ; 
    01-01-2016 --> OPEN/ACTIVE (**DESIRED OUTPUT)**
```

Whenever I attempt to use MAX function to pull the most recent enrollment; it will always pulls each iteration of the enrollment periods. How do I direct SQL to only pull the most recent EFFECTIVE DATE, while also only pulling its corresponding TERMINATION DATE (be it NULL or populated) and excluding everything prior?

I still want to pull TERMED records; its just than when I do **`MAX`** on both EFFECTIVE and TERM; it mixes the data and will pull the MAX/EFF but will also erroneously pull a MAX/TERM from another instance of enrollment.

Please let me know if any clarification is necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way of doing this uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by eff_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common use case. There are several ways to write this code. Depending on the SQL engine used, they will be of different speeds.

I will use fairly generic column names. Tweak as needed.

```
SELECT common_id, msg
FROM myTable outerTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM myTable innerTable
    WHERE innerTable.common_id = outerTable.common_id
      AND innerTable.time > outerTable.time
  )
```

Please note that if there are two rows with identical `common_id` and `time` columns, then both will show up in the output. You can replace the `>` with `>=` to hide both of those rows.

The other common approach is kind of difficult to make sense of, but here goes. Notice the similarities to the `NOT EXISTS` approach.

```
SELECT outerTable.common_id, outerTable.msg
FROM myTable outerTable
LEFT JOIN myTable innerTable
  ON  innerTable.common_id = outerTable.common_id
  AND innerTable.time > outerTable.time
WHERE innerTable.common_id IS NULL
```

In SQL Server, this second approach is typically faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM coverage ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Edit: Above is understood by postgresql, mysql and others. You need

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM coverage ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

instead (thanks to Barry...).

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM coverage WHERE start_date = (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM coverage)
```

You most probably need to join this with some other table to get only the records for 'John Doe' - but as you did not provide any database layout, I'll leave this to you.

Comment: I don't think that `LIMIT 1` is valid for SQL Server.  IIRC, that's Oralce syntax, or maybe MySql.  T-SQL uses `SELECT TOP (1)...`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually, postgres, although I know mysql supports it, too.